# Help me slice and code this footer?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Hee lads,

I'm now finished with my footer design and I sliced it up already but I just can't seem to find a good way to code this thing.. 
I sliced it up like 1px width and the headers separtly and also dont forget the spacers...

Can't fine a good way to code this thing damn
Heres a picture to it.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/51/footerws.jpg/

Would be really glad if someone could help :)

Comment: I too would be glad for someone to do my work for me.

Comment: do we get money? I like money

Comment: this is not the place to ask people to do stuff for you, this is a place to ask for help.

Comment: Hahaha :P No it's more like... If someone could tell me like to slice it in 3 parts.. or 2 parts and simply a short explanation how to code it in css... Nothing more :P

Comment: I guess my explanation is a bit wrong.. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/EQsAX/1/

*It's like the picture you provided*

Comment: You 2 Thanks man really appriciate it! Helps alot

Answer (score 1):

This way you can use different positions of one image in different elements.

Note that it does even help to Not always slice images into small pieces.
One perk is that the images load at the same time ( or image to be specific ). Especially in a menu hover effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/FyMW6/

CSS:

```
ul li { 
    background-image: url("http://lorempixum.com/g/400/200/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;

    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first { background-position: -30px -0px; }
.second { background-position: -100px -0px; }
.third { background-position: -50px 0px; }
```

-0px was unintentional mistake on my part.. use 0px

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="second"></li>
    <li class="third"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks man really appriciate it! Helps alot